# How to extract text from element having text in brackets in cypress i.e. test(5)

Tags: text, cypress, extract

Can someone pls help in extracting text from element. Let us say we have element shown in page having text 'Test(10).
How we can get text as o/p Test and 10 separately.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex with name capture group.

```js
// example for 'Test(10)'
cy.get('.element-selector')
  .invoke('text')
  .then(elText => {
    const matcher = /(?<text>test)\((?<number>\d+)\)/
    // extracts 'Test'
    const text = elText.match(matcher)?.groups?.text
    // extracts '10'
    const num = elText.match(matcher)?.groups?.num
  })
```

Comment: I tried this and added closing tag as well but it (?<text>test</text>)\((?<number>\d+)\</number>);. At 1st ?, it says expression expected then at / invalid character.

Comment: You placed `</text>` in the regex. I dont have that in the answer.

Comment: true but it was expecting closing tag then I added.Post that also const matcher line were having issues like expression expected and for / it says invalid character.Anything i need to import or something else is there.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I copy/pasted from a regex site I so I forgot to add the `/` at the begin and end of the matcher.

Comment: Thank you! it worked. Also any idea like how we can browse file from local if input type is not File. Actually in page there is a only link to browse file from local (but no field to input value). I had tried using attachFile but i think that will not work here.